# forms called by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

how can i get a form to work properly when it is loaded in the html injected by ajax? im using jquery if its any help...

Comment: Define "work properly". What problem are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: im using the validator plugin and submiting to a form to email php file, when the form is called by ajax, it wont validate at all and instead of submitting data to the php file, it is redirecting the browser to it, viewing the file instead of submitting data to it.

Answer (score 1):

i have solved this, all i had to do use the live function of jquery.